# How to kill oozie coordinator actions using oozie client

Tags: oozie

OOzie 4.2   has provided the documentation for killing co-ordinator actions, however I am not able to know the exacts values to be passed rangetType and scope.

Could any one elaborate it or provide a concrete example.

```
public List<CoordinatorAction> kill(String jobId,
                           String rangeType,
                           String scope)
                             throws OozieClientException
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the source code of [`OozieClient`](https://github.com/apache/oozie/blob/release-4.2.0/client/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/client/OozieClient.java) where also this API is used to see the possible values. In particular see the implementation of  following method

```
 private void jobCommand(CommandLine commandLine) throws IOException, OozieCLIException {

}
```

This same API is used by Oozie Command line tool which can be referred from [here](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_CommandLineTool.html).

rangeType : Possible values 'date' or 'action'

scope : Possible values 'date' or 'action'

> $oozie job -kill  [-action 1, 3-4, 7-40] [-date
>   2009-01-01T01:00Z::2009-05-31T23:59Z, 2009-11-10T01:00Z,
>   2009-12-31T22:00Z]
>
> Either -action or -date should be given. **If neither -action nor -date
>   is given, the exception will be thrown. Also if BOTH -action and -date
>   are given, an error will be thrown**. Multiple ranges can be used in
>   -action or -date. See the above example. If one of the actions in the given list of -action is already in terminal state, the output of this
>   command will only include the other actions. The dates specified in
>   -date must be UTC. Single date specified in -date must be able to find an action with matched nominal time to be effective. After the command
>   is executed the killed coordinator action will have KILLED status.

Comment: It does not help me. I donot find any specific definition.

Comment: Could you please clear me , Where is the scope parameter defined in command line argument, it just have range type which is either data or action number. I really donot understand what is the significance of scope here. I am referring oozie 4.2 client api.